# Test if the number is prime in Java

Tags: java

Test if the number is prime or not:

This is my code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x){
      if(x<=1) 
         return false;
      else if(x==2) 
         return true;
      else {
         for(int i=2; i<=x/2; i++){                        
             if(x%i==0) 
                return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
   }
```

My question is: the last statement 'return true', if the number is a prime, then no false return, but if the number is not a prime, then during the for loop, there will be a false return. And when the loop is finished, the program execute the statement below for loop--‘return true’. So I am wondering if the returned true will cover the returned false that happened during for loop. (Although when I am testing this code, the code works well for testing a number is prime or not, but I don't know why)

Comment: Debugger is your best friend. It will make your day when you find out `why` on your own.

Comment: How did you get this to work when you tested it?  I get `ArithmeticException: / by zero`.  Did you type it in wrong?

Comment: @ajb I typed wrong, for loop, i should start from i=2, sorry for this

Comment: also have a look at `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`

Answer (score 5):

After `return false` (or any return statement), the method will return without executing anything else, so `return true` won't be reached in this case, and therefore your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you start the iteration on zero?**

Consider what would happen when `i = 1`:

```
if(x % i == 0)    // i = 1, so x % i will be zero
    return false;
```

Even more, consider what would happen when `i = 0`:

```
if(x % i == 0)    // how would you define x % 0!?
```

Start the iteration on 2:

```
// ...
for(int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i++) {
    if(x % i == 0)
        return false;
}
return true;
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have corrected it to int i=2 in my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement makes the method exit, so if "return false" is executed the method exit returning false and return true will never be executed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well it did provide the answer but I'll admit my answer was undevelopped. I corrected it, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` ends the method. When we say `return`, that means "stop what you're doing and give this value back to the method that called us."

**Cases where this doesn't happen**

- `try`-`finally` blocks, any `return` statement or exception thrown in the `finally` block of a `try` block will override the returned value.
- `System.exit`, this method never returns, so any statements after an `exit` call will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`if(x%i==0) return false;`

if this condition comes true then it will return false and will not execute anything after that

and when above condition will be false it wil return true.